# Postgresql function with table as input? Is dynamic SQL in a plpgsql function the way to go?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a common situation that comes up where I want to join with a table moredata. To give the simplest example, imagine I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM x 
JOIN moredata d on x.yyyymmdd = d.yyyymmdd
```

`x` will vary while `moredata` stays the same. **What's a good way stylistically to reuse code, automate the above so that I can apply it to different tables (eg. do the same thing on table 'y' instead of 'x')?**

One way would be to write a plpgsql function using dynamic SQL that operates on the name of the table. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION joinmoredata(tblname text) RETURNS TABLE(...) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I JOIN moredata on ...', tblname);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But then you couldn't apply it to a derived table or a CTE. Is there a better way? Or is dynamic SQL the best way to reuse code in this situation?

(Note, the actual query is a lot more complicated than `SELECT * FROM x JOIN moredata d on x.yyyymmdd = d.yyyymmdd` which is why I want to reuse code.)

Comment: what should be function returnes ?

Comment: `x will vary` .. how exactly? Does each table have the same columns? (types, names, number)? And will the return type `RETURNS TABLE (...)` vary also?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `x` can be standardized so that it has the same columns each time and the table the functions returns has the same columns each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use the same column names with the same data types from each table in place of `x` and return the same row type, that's a good candidate for dynamic SQL. Exactly like you already have in your question. Your use of `format()` with `%I` suggests you are aware of how to sanitize identifiers avoid syntax errors and SQL injection.

You need to have a plan for privilege management. And I would pass schema-qualified table names or data type `regclass` to avoid confusion with table name resolution and possibly other tables with the same name in a different schema.

Closely related, with more details:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

If it gets more complicated - varying column names and types - you can always concatenate query strings in a client program ...

Answer (score 1):

I can only say that I use dynamic SQL any time I need to reuse bigger parts of SQL code and change only something in WHERE clause or table names etc. And it works OK and I do this way also very complicated CTE queries containing also INSERTs or UPDATESs and it works. So I would vote for dynamic SQL.